# read data from bluetooth Pulse oximeter in react native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am building a react native app to interface with a ble pulse oximeter [amazon link here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D7MDXCU). This is the JSON that i have found. The service UUID is : `636F6D2E-6A69-7561-6E2E-504F56313100` and characteristic UUID is : `7274782E-6A69-7561-6E2E-504F56313100` for reading the data from oximeter, I only have these two things, but i dont know what Hex i need to send to retrieve the SpO2 and PRbpm.

Would really appreciate any help or thoughts you guys have. Thanks!

````
  "name": "Pulse Oximeter",
  "id": "D0:5F:B8:3D:4D:25",
  "rssi": -65,
  "services": [
    "1800",
    "1801",
    "636f6d2e-6a69-7561-6e2e-504f56313100",
    "180a"
  ],
  "characteristics": [
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a00",
      "properties": [
        "Read",
        "WriteWithoutResponse",
        "Write"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a01",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a02",
      "properties": [
        "Read",
        "Write"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a03",
      "properties": [
        "Write"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a04",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1801",
      "characteristic": "2a05",
      "properties": [
        "Indicate"
      ],
      "descriptors": [
        {
          "uuid": "2902"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "636f6d2e-6a69-7561-6e2e-504f56313100",
      "characteristic": "7274782e-6a69-7561-6e2e-504f56313100",
      "properties": [
        "WriteWithoutResponse",
        "Write",
        "Notify"
      ],
      "descriptors": [
        {
          "uuid": "2902"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "2901"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a23",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a24",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a25",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a26",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a27",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a28",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a29",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a2a",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a50",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a30",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a31",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    }
  ]
}```
````

Comment: You want to connect to a custom service, without the proper documentation it will be quite difficult. The communication could also be encrypted or use a special protocol to ensure that everyone is using the official app. You probably have the best chance if you use a BLE sniffer to analyse the communication between the device and the official app. The sniffer from [nordic](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-sniffer-for-bluetooth-le) can be used together with Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

This could help: https://github.com/chichengjunma/iHealthDeviceLabs-Android

Not sure where to look but this is the old iHealth repo...

**Maybe someone else can add some color based on this.** https://github.com/chichengjunma/iHealthDeviceLabs-Android/blob/master/examples/DeviceLibTest/src/com/ihealth/devices/Po3.java